# How to revoke express-jwt tokens in express.js / passport-http-bearer

Tags: express, jwt, express-jwt

This is my router:

```
expressJwt    = require('express-jwt')
router.post '/signin'      , controller.signUp
router.get  '/signout/:id' , expressJwt(secret:secretToken,  isRevoked: isRevokedCallback), controller.signOut
```

This is my signOut endpoint:

```
exports.signOut = (req, res) ->
  console.log res.user
```

What do I need to put into my endpoint to revoke the token.

I tried putting this function into my router:

```
isRevokedCallback = (req, payload, done) ->
  for key, value of payload
    console.log(key + ' ' + value)
  # The below part does not work. Also I don't know what data should refer to
  issuer = payload.iss
  tokenId = payload.jti
  data.getRevokedToken issuer, tokenId, (err, token) ->
    if err
      return done(err)
    done null, ! !token
  return
```

The list comprehension indeed logs out:

```
iat 1436437563
exp 1436653563
```

And there is also also a user object in my endpoint logged out:

```
user [object Object]
```

Now how to put the pieces together and revoke the JWT Token, so that the user who's token it is is not able to login anymore with that Token (or alternatively expire it immeadiately)?

Here is some sample console log of my user object:

```
{ user: 
   { __v: 0,
     _id: '559e6aad50cdf686db31ea55',
     local: 
      { password: '$2a$08$YBvzOWADlw9tZCDh3aG/j.gV.Tbaesk3pLbbiHL/lkGaC08bSbGmy',
        email: 'dieter@mustermann.de' } },
  iat: 1436445357,
  exp: 1436661357 }
GET /user/signout/559e6aad50cdf686db31ea55 401 2.530 ms - 12
ERROR:Error: expected 200 "OK", got 401 "Unauthorized"
    1) should sign out via passport.js
```

Comment: Hi, may I know how do you use coffeescript in expressjs?

Answer (score 0):

I managed this by returning a `token: false` key, value pair. Another idea would be to send back a token with `expirationInSeconds: 1`. The old token will still be valid, and this can't be called very secure at all. So set the default token expiration very low or move to another option like blacklists.